How to handle both SPLs and native SOL token in my contract?
Hi I was working on making a contract that should support both SOL and SPL tokens.
Is there a recommended way to manage SOL and SPL token altogether? It looks like we need to wrap SOL to make it work.  A way I an thinking to do is ask the user to wrap it first, but it doesn't feel really user friendly.
Is there a recommended way to do that? I was thinking a function that could look like that:
pub fn function_one(ctx: Context<Game>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {

    is_spl = detect_if_spl()
    
    if not spl { 
      wrap_sol() 
    }
   ...
   ...
}


Thank you!

You need to wrap sol in the client and then you can use it like a normal SPL token.
Afterwards you can unwrap it again.
https://solana.com/de/developers/cookbook/tokens/manage-wrapped-sol

But this will ask the users using to have to make  2 transactions  instead of one? Or is there a way to do both operations client side in one go?

You can have multiple instructions in the same transaction
